What is the expected number of OAuth2 client logins with Webflux and Spring Security on immediate HTTP requests?
Currently we're monitoring a lot of client logins at our identity provider and I'd like to make sure what we could expect here from Spring Security.
Our setup is as follows
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun authorizedClientManager(
        clientRegistrationRepository: ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository,
        authorizedClientService: ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService,
    ): ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager =
        AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
            clientRegistrationRepository,
            authorizedClientService,
        )
            .apply {
                val authorizedClientProvider: ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider =
                    ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                        .clientCredentials()
                        .build()

                setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider)
            }

    @Bean
    fun customizer(
        authorizedClientManager: ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager,
    ): WebClientCustomizer = WebClientCustomizer {
        it.filter(ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager))
    }
}

and later on we run something along every 15 minutes
client.doInitialRequest()
    .flatMap { client.doEvenMoreRequests() } // around 10k

Current token lifespan is 5 minutes (the requests are done in 1 minute though). Auth flow is client_credentials.
It looks like that this code produces between 200 and 700 client logins on our identiy provider.
Shouldn't the client be authorized after the initial request and then just use the already present auth token in the subsequent requests?
I tried to increase token lifespan to 1 hour and it looks like that it's working after the initial roundtrip is done. Then again after 1 hour 200 to 700 logins.

In the meantime I reproduced (the known race condition https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11461) on my side and drafted a solution in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/15295
If anyone comes across this feel free to give feedback/improve my implementation.
